# Manipulate a clocked signal in order to get 10 pulses

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, counter, clock, xilinx

I am attempting to create a very specific signal in my code. Basically I need a signal to be generated after load_0 ends, in the falling edge, where such signal would be 10 pulses of the 1KHz signal and the rest 0. Which is just preserving 10 pulses that are aligned with the variable Serial_out.

Thus far I have tried an if to attempt this, with a counter to attempt to count to 10 for the 10 pulses i want and discarding the rest. This always ends either not being able to be synthesized due to error or the test bench clk_trig never being initialized.

My coding is quite crude due to the fact that I have not been using xilinx for long.

Main section of the code

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY HAMMING IS
    PORT ( CLK_50MHz_M : IN  STD_LOGIC;
             RST  : IN STD_LOGIC;
             LOAD_O : IN STD_LOGIC;
             input1 : IN STD_LOGIC;
             input2 : IN STD_LOGIC;
             input3 : IN STD_LOGIC;
             input4 : IN STD_LOGIC;
             input5 : IN STD_LOGIC;
             input6 : IN STD_LOGIC;
             CLK_DIV_O : OUT STD_LOGIC;
             CLK_TRIG : OUT STD_LOGIC;
             Serial_out : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END HAMMING;

ARCHITECTURE ARCH OF HAMMING IS
SIGNAL input_vec : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 1);
SIGNAL output : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL CLK_100Hz, CLK_50KHz : STD_LOGIC;


COMPONENT P2S
     port(
         clk : in STD_LOGIC;
         reset : in STD_LOGIC;
         load : in STD_LOGIC;
         din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
         dout : out STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT SCALE_CLOCK
        PORT (CLK_50MHz_S : IN  STD_LOGIC;
                RST       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
                CLK_100Hz   : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;

begin
----------------------------------------------
process (LOAD_O, CLK_100Hz)
begin
    if (LOAD_O = '1') then CLK_TRIG <= '0';    -crude attempt at the desired signal
    ELSE
    CLK_TRIG <= CLK_100Hz;
    end if;
end process;
---------------------------------------------

-- BITS DE PALABRA
output(2) <= input_vec(1);
output(4) <= input_vec(2);
output(5) <= input_vec(3);
output(6) <= input_vec(4);
output(8) <= input_vec(5);
output(9) <= input_vec(6);

-- BIT PARIEDAD
output(0) <= input_vec(1) XOR input_vec(2) XOR input_vec(4) XOR input_vec(5);
output(1) <= input_vec(1) XOR input_vec(3) XOR input_vec(4) XOR input_vec(6);
output(3) <= input_vec(2) XOR input_vec(3) XOR input_vec(4);
output(7) <= input_vec(5) XOR input_vec(6);

ClockDiv: SCALE_CLOCK PORT MAP(CLK_50MHz_S => CLK_50MHz_M, RST => RST, CLK_100Hz => CLK_100Hz);
SeriesOut: P2S PORT MAP(clk => CLK_100Hz, din => output, dout =>  Serial_out, reset => RST, load => LOAD_O);

CLK_DIV_O <= CLK_100Hz;
input_vec <= input1 & input2 & input3 & input4 & input5 & input6;
END ARCH;
```

[FPGA2 code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZOHD.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for your waveform, but you should show your code, without that there is very little we can do. Just as a heads-up beware **not** to make 10 clock pulses using a gated clock. That is generally a very, very bad idea. Also there are inherent issue with gated clocks and FPGAs.

Comment: Ah yes sorry my bad, i have updated the question with the main section of the code.

Comment: Ah yes i have seen that warning that some clocks that i have used are not suitable for the Spartan 6, i would like to fix them but time isn't on my side, thought thus far it has somewhat behaved like in the simulations.

Comment: Where does your 100Hz clock come from? Do you make that yourself from the 50MHz? if so you should be able to fix your code easily.

Comment: Yes the 100hz are from a prescaler derived from the main fpga clock, it is only used to spew the data out in serial. Then the approach im trying to attempt with a counter is plausible?. i have had no luck making it work thought

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 50MHz clock.
from that you probably decided to make a nice 50/50 100Hz clock and then use that.
That is the wrong strategy!

You always want as much as possible a synchronous design.

If you want signals to change at 100Hz the right (synchronous) method is as follows:

- Make 100Hz pulses which are high for **one** 50MHz clock only. (e.g. P100Hz)
- Everywhere you use a 100Hz clock go back to using the 50 MHz clock
  then in the 50MHz clock section use an additional `if P100Hz then`

You now have a synchronous design running at effectively 100Hz.